# Avoid using implementation types like 'ArrayList'; use the interface instead (Serialization issue)

Tags: java, list, serialization, arraylist, interface

**Please note this is not a "program against interface" type of question**

I am getting *Avoid using implementation types like 'ArrayList'; use the interface instead* in PMD when using an ArrayList. I understand why I am getting it, but in this case I **can't use List because Lists aren't Serializable, but ArrayLists are**

Do I have any alternative  instead of deactivating that PMD check?

Comment: Not convinced that matters. Serialization happens as runtime therefore the compile time type is not really relevant. The runtime type will be written out and the right type deserialized.

Comment: It's not a serialization isue. If the actual type is serializable, you don't have a problem.

Comment: @BoristheSpider What if what is binary? And what does '(too soon)' mean? What are you talking about?

Comment: @BoristheSpider It is no more funny this time than it was the last time, when you repeatedly denied quotations from official documentation. What you're doing now defeats me entirely. Please stop it.

Comment: @EJP my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to you problem would be using generics with [multiple type bound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-TypeBound) instead of specifying `ArrayList` explicitly.

Instead of writing:

```
public byte[] doSomething(final ArrayList<?> serializableList) {
    serializableList.add(getSomeObject()); // List.add()
    return SerializationUtils.serialize(serializableList); // Serializable
}
```

You can write:

```
public <T extends List<?> & Serializable> byte[] doSomething(final T serializableList) {
    serializableList.add(getSomeObject()); // List.add()
    return SerializationUtils.serialize(serializableList); // Serializable
}
```

That way, your method can take as parameter everything extending `List` and `Serializable` (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, ...).